# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() is giving me a chain reaction of forced unwrapped optionals I don't want in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type, forceunwrap

I'm confused about using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` in Swift, making me force unwrap it, even though it is defined with `let`. Adding in the `?` or `!` is making my code look messy and making me change everything after it. I'd like to not require this when defining scaledImage.

```
let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let scaledCIImage:CIImage = (scaledImage?.ciImage)! // makes me force upwrap

// gives error 'Value of optional type 'CIFilter?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?'
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage]).outputImage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of legitimate uses of `!` if you know when to use it properly.

From the documentation for `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`:

> If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_:), this function returns nil.

Since you are using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and your current context isn't `nil`, then `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` won't return a `nil` so it is safe to force-unwrap.

```
let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
```

As for creating the `CIImage`, the `CIFilter`, and the file `CIImage`, safely unwrap using `if let`.

```
if let scaledCIImage = scaledImage.ciImage,
   let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage]),
   let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
    // Do what you need with outputImage
}
```

Update based on your comments:

Given that `scaledmage.ciImage` is `nil` and you want to try to create a `CIImage` from the `cgImage`, you can update the chain of `if let` to:

```
if let cgImage = scaledImage.cgImage {
    let scaledCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage]),
       let outputImage = filter.outputImage {
        // Do what you need with outputImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this is such a mess. I just found out the scaledImage.ciImage is nil, so it must be a CGImage? But if I use if let scaledCIImage = CIImage(cgImage: scaledCGImage.cgImage) it's complaining "Value of optional type 'CGImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" And I can't find any way out.

Answer (score 1):

> Adding in the ? or ! is making my code look messy and making me change everything after it.

Well, whether it's messy is quite subjective. Swift is designed this way to make you think about each optional you unwrap carefully. By doing this, you can avoid lots of those "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" errors.

Methods and properties return `nil` for a reason. Usually the reason is that an error occurred, the thing couldn't be done, or there is no valid value for a property. You should think about these problems - "what should my method do if this method returns `nil`?"

If you want to do something else when the value is `nil` (i.e. it being nil is not fatal to your logic), use a `if let` statement. e.g.

```
if let scaledCIImage = scaledImage?.ciImage {
    // deal with the scaledCIImage
} else {
    // do something else to remedy. The method can still continue running
}
```

If your method couldn't continue if the value is nil, then you can consider writing a guard statement:

```
guard let scaledCIImage = scaledImage?.ciImage else { 
    // you need to return some value or call "fatalError()" here
}
```

If you are absolutely sure that the value could not be nil, force unwrap it:

```
let scaledCIImage = scaledImage!.ciImage!
```

For the second error, you can fix it like:

```
// with force unwrapping
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage])!.outputImage!

// if let
if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage])?.outputImage {
    // ...
}

// guard let
guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineTile", withInputParameters:[kCIInputImageKey:scaledCIImage])?.outputImage else {
    // ...
}
```

You can chain all of these together in a big `if let` or `guard let` statement like rmaddy has shown.